# Xcode 11 Error connecting with Parse to Amazon Web Service

Tags: swift, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to connect to my AWS server, but when I try to save an object there, Xcode cannot reach and trow me this error:

Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=0 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized, NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0})

Here's my code on appDelegate:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "*******"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "****************"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://ec2-3-22-186-169.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse"
    })

    Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)
    testParseSave()
    return true
}

func testParseSave() {
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "MyTestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            print("El objeto se ha guardado en Parse correctamente.")
        } else {
            if error != nil {
                print("is NOT nil:")
                print (error as Any)
            } else {
                print("IS nil:")
                print ("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This error uses to happen when the keys do not match. Can you please double check with the ones you have initialized your parse server?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thanks! I'm going to check this out